# Let $a,b \in \mathbb Z$. Prove that if $3 \mid (a+2b)$ then $3 \mid (2a+b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb Z$. Prove that if $3 \mid (a+2b)$ then $3 \mid (2a+b)$

This is how I solved this: 
$3m = a+2b \iff a = 3m-2b$ 
$2a+b = 2(3m-2b)+b = 6m -3b = 3(2m-b)$
 And now, my solution seems to work. However, when - instead of solving for $a$, I solve for $b$, then I get this: 
$2a+b = 3 \frac{a+m}{2}$ 
How can I even be sure that this number is an integer? 
Is there a way to fix the second solution? If my first solution is correct. the second one should work as well.

Comment: I can't see where the problem is: since $2a+b$ is an integer, however you write it it remains an integer. There is no fix to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me actually address your question rather than just giving an answer.
Both solutions work. For the second one:

> when - instead of solving for $a$, I solve for $b$, then I get this: 
>   $2a+b = 3 \frac{a+m}{2}$ 
>   How can I even be sure that this number is an integer?

To complete the argument, notice that $2a + b$ is an integer (obviously); therefore, $3 \frac{a + m}{2}$ is an integer. And because it's an integer, $\frac{a + m}{2}$ must be an integer (since $3$ does not cancel $2$). This means that it is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 4):

$3|a+2b$ then $3|2a+4b$ then $3|2a+4b-3b = 2a+b$.

Of course, you can also reverse this. If $3|2a+b$ then $3|2a+4b = 2(a+2b)$ Now use Euclid lemma and we have $3|a+2b$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $a-3m=-2b$, $a+m = 4m-2b = 2(2m-b)$ which is even and thus is divisible by two. Both of your solutions work, but the first one is cleaner since it does not involve the division by two.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to observe that 
$$3a+3b \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \Leftrightarrow a+2b \equiv -2a-b \pmod{3} \tag{1}$$
and the relation becomes **$\iff$**.

$\color{red}{\Rightarrow}$ If $3 \mid a+2b$ then $a+2b \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and from $(1)$ we hqve $0 \equiv -2a-b \pmod{3}$ or $0 \equiv 2a+b \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 3 \mid 2a+b$.

$\color{red}{\Leftarrow}$ If $3 \mid 2a+b$ then $2a+b \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and from $(1)$
$$-a-2b \equiv 2a+b \pmod{3} \Rightarrow -a-2b \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$
or $a+2b \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow 3 \mid a+2b$.

Comment: Consider using \iff to get $\iff$

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use congruences ? They usually show the right short way in this kind of divisibility questions. Here you want to prove that $a+2b \equiv 0$ mod $3$ iff $2a+b \equiv 0$ mod $3$. But $2\equiv -1$ mod $3$, so the two conditions are immediately equivalent to $a\equiv b$ mod $3$.